# Disable border-left on a link if the link extends to a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question regarding an issue I am having with a pipe separator between links in a subnav bar.  My links have a left-border of one pixel (the pipe separator) with the first link disabling the left-border.  My issue is, when the links expand past their container and extend to a new line, the first link on the new line will have a border-left of one pixel.  So, my question is, how do I disable the border-left if the link is the first element on a new line?  Keep in mind that the number of links and the name of the links in my subnav changes depending on the page the user is currently on.  So, "nth-child()" selector seems to be out of the question.  I was thinking of using the JQuery .offset() method...but this doesn't seem to be the correct way of going about it.  Any help or suggestions would be great.

Thanks you,
-Kyle

Here is an example: 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/erwiky/W4HrK/24/)

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
    <a href="#">Link 9</a>
    <a href="#">Link 10</a>
</div>

.container {
    width: 300px;
}

.container a {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    float: left;
}

.container a:first-child {
    border-left: none;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a right-border instead, where the last link disables the right-border? Of course it would have a right-border before a newline, but would this suit your purpose?

Comment: How about this : http://jsfiddle.net/gUk5r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make every link have a left border (so just remove the code for the first link), move them 1px to the left with `margin-left: -1px` and cut the border off with `overflow: hidden`. See http://jsfiddle.net/3DU6d/